# How can i open new activity clicking an item in listview in Android Studio?

Tags: android

How can i open new activity clicking an item in listview in Android Studio? Or more precisely- I´ve just one problem with it. The problem is described in code. Sorry for my english!!! Here´s the code  `

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ListView listView;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
String[] android_versions= { "Jelly Bean", "Kitkat", "Donut",
        "Eclair", "Froyo", "Honeycomb", "Ice Cream"
         };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,android_versions);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        //Here´s the problem! The super.OnItemClick 
        //doesn´t work.//


            super.OnItemClick(parent, view, position, id);

         //Here´s the problem! The super. doesn´t work.//

            if (position == 0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, JellyBean.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            else if (position == 1) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, Kitkat.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            else if (position == 2) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, Donut.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

`

Answer (score 1):

delete ***super.OnItemClick(parent, view, position, id);***

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), JellyBean.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: v check button click for me ;)

Answer (score 0):

As `ItemClickListener` is an **interface**, there is no `super` implementation, so you can remove `super.OnItemClick`